# Javascript this not referring to current object in backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, scope, this

I have a tree-like backbone model, something like:

```
var Leaf = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "tests.json",
    initialize: function() {
        if (Array.isArray(this.get('children'))) {
            var childTree = new Tree();
            childTree.on("add",this.addChild);
            childTree.add(this.get('children'));
            this.set({children: childTree});
        }
    },


    addChild : function(child){
        console.log(this);console.log(child);
    },

});


var Tree = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Leaf,
    url: "tests.json",
});
```

`addChild` is called for each element added to `childTree` in the initialization method.
But inside the `addChild` method, `this` refers to the `childTree` collection instead of the model... I'm relatively unexperienced with javascript, and it doesn't make sense to me at all... Is this correct behavior, and how can I bind the listener to the model inside `addChild` ?

The JSON is something like:

```
[{
    "name":"root",
    "children":[
        {
            "name":"inner",
            "children":[{
                "name":"innerinner",
                "attr":{"class":""},
                "checked":true,
                "locked":true,
                "children":[]
            }]
     }]
}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
childTree.on("add", _.bind(this.addChild, this));
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but can you explain a bit what is happening and why I need to use this `_.bind` method (or why `this` was referring to the collection)

Comment: You could also use the third argument to [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on): `childTree.on('add', this.addChild, this)`.

Comment: In JS 'this' depends on the context from which a function is called. In your case you just took the function 'addChild' and passed it in as callback. The function was decoupled from the model, thats why 'this' referenced 'childTree'. To actually bind 'this' to the Model it was necessary to use underscores _.bind() method. For more information look at: http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html

Comment: [Understanding JavaScript Function Invocation and “this”](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) covers the topic nicely too.